# Unidentified Network for HyperV Internal Switch

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I am trying to setup a HyperV internal switch for the guest OS on a Windows Server 2012 host. After creating the new Internal Switch through Virtual Switch Manager, I can see the virtual adapter under Network Connections. But, it is listed as an "Unidentified Network".

The host system has only one plugged in NIC which has been configured with static IPs. The idea is to share the internet with the internal switch through Internet Connection Sharing.

I was able to do the same on another box with Windows Server 2012 without any issues.

Please see the attached screenshots. The ones suffixed with 1 are from the new system where it does not work and the ones suffixed with 2 are from the old one where it works.

Notice how the Internal switch appears under the networks in case 1 but not in case 2. Server #2 has the active directory role added but I don't think it can (lack of it) be the cause.

**Network 1**

[image: Network 1]

**Network 2**

[image: Network 2]

**Adapters 1**

[image: Adapters 1]

**Adapters 2**

[image: Adapters 2]

**ipconfig 1**

[image: ipconfig 1]

**ipconfig 2**

[image: ipconfig 2]

Comment: Hyper-V and ICS running on a domain controller. You're practically begging for trouble.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @lordvlad It seems to work if I disable the physical adapter and then re-enable it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your virtual adapter is listed as an *unidentified network* is because it does not have an IPv4 default gateway assigned. Get that specified in Network Connections and you'll be on your way.

Comment: But if he set default gateway for Internal switch - 66.171.178.177 , gateway and IP address(192.168.137.1) are not on same subnet = error !